# How to import python module as a specific reference?

Tags: python, python-import

I had a file at `db/connection.py`. I moved the file and now the path is `project/db/connection.py`.
Previously I imported that file using this syntax:

```
import db.connection
```

And somewhere in the code I had access to the file:

```
db.connection.open_connection()
```

Since now the file is moved, I know only two options to import the file: using `import` and `from import` keywords. But both of them will change the reference to the file. I'll show you what I mean.
If I use `import`:

```
import project.db.connection
```

Then the new reference is `project.db.connection` and I need to change the code that accesses the file as well, so that it becomes:

```
project.db.connection.open_connection()
```

If I use `from import`:

```
from project.db import connection
```

The same problem, but now the reference is `connection`.

I thought I could do that:

```
from project import db.connection
```

But python gives me an error at that line of code:

```
from project import db.connection
                     ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So if it's possible, how to import the new file having the reference `db.connection`, so I don't need to change the code that accesses that file?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you can just do: import x as db.connection

Comment: @einekratzekkatze, unfortunately, the same syntax error at line `import project.db.connection as db.connection`

Comment: `from project.db import connection`…‽

Comment: @deceze, this syntax imports the file as `connection`, but not as `db.connection`

Comment: Yeah, but if you always take care to import it as `connection`, then that's fine…

Comment: Quite frankly, this is mostly a non-issue. If you rename some stuff, then yes, you'll need to rename some stuff. If you're lucky you can cover it by changing one `import` statement, but probably you'll need to do a find-replace on your source code. This shouldn't be something that's necessary very often, as you probably won't be renaming stuff constantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from project import db
```

Maybe you need to add `__init__.py` file in `project` and in `project/db`.